# How to write query to get specific data from pivot table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm still a beginner in Laravel. I'm trying to write a query to get categories which are associated with specific place. I have the following three tables

```
place    place_categorye    category
------   ----------------   -------------
id            place_id         id
name          category_id       name

each place has number of categories
```

what I want to do is when I choose `place_id` I get the categories associated with it in the pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I supposed that you have a Many To Many relation between `places` and `categories` then in your Place Model

```
public function categories(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'place_categorye', 'place_id', 'category_id');
}
```

And now you can access the categories of a certain Place like below:

```
$place->categories;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the relationship definitions, it is hard to give an answer on the ORM queries, but here is a raw query which will give you the expected result,

```
DB::select(DB::raw("
select category.id, category.name
from place
         join place_categorye on place_categorye.place_id = place.id
         join category on category.id = place_categorye.category_id
where place.id = 1");
```

if you want the results inclusive of all the null values, depending on the use case you can use a `left join` instead of `join` (`join` means `innter join` by default)

Answer (score 0):

** to many relationship** for this

```
<?php

namespace App\PlaceCategory;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
class PlaceCategory extends Pivot {

    public function place()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Place');
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

}
```

category Model

```
public function places()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Place')
        ->using('App\PlaceCategory');
}
```

Place Model

```
public function categpries()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category')
        ->using('App\PlaceCategory');
}
```

Now you can access this easily & can query easily .
Like 
$place=Place::with('categories')->first();
by using
$place->categories we get all the categories for this place